# Skip MySQL password

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

I am executing this command-

```
mysql -u user1 -p password1 -e "show databases"
```

and I expect to run the mysql "show databases" command successfully. But It's not happening that way. It's asking for password again, even though I've entered the correct password. This is what I get-

```
Enter password:
```

How can I get rid of this prompt where it asks for password even though I've given in my command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put a space after -p

```
mysql -u user1 -ppassword1 -e "show databases"
```